# How to parse/render a html string with Dojo 1.10?

Tags: javascript, dojo, substitution

Let's say I have the following :

```
const props = {
    buttonText : 'Click Me'
}

const htmlString = "<button>${buttonText}</button>"

dojo.someFunction(htmlString, props);
```

What would be the `dojo` module equivalent of "`someFunction`"?

I understand it can be done with `templateMixins`, but I don't want to extend/make a widget, only borrow the parsing function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is using the [dojo/string](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/string.html) `->`  [substitude](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/string.html#substitute) function that's used in the dojo Dijit’s templating.

See below working snippet :

```js
require(["dojo/string", "dojo/dom","dojo/ready"], function(string, dom , ready) {

  const props = {
    buttonText: 'Click Me'
  }

  const htmlString = "<button>${buttonText}</button>"
  
  var newString = string.substitute(htmlString, props);
  console.log(newString);
  alert("String after substute : \n"+ newString);
  dom.byId("btn").innerHTML = newString ;
  
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  dojoConfig = {
    isDebug: true,
    async: true,
    parseOnLoad: true
  }
</script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="btn"></div>
```